# How modify css in gulp stream and save correct source maps?

Tags: gulp, source-maps

There is a need to change the css code in gulp stream (add to image path ?hash), but does not spoil the source maps, present in the file. Currently unable to process css file, but sourcemaps distorted (previous original maps are not stored). I understand I need a plug-in for this vinyl-sourcemaps-apply and rework + rework-url.

```
gulp.src('./source/css/**/*.css')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(concat('main.css'))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
        cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(antiCache(fileHashes))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
```

where `filHashes` is json object `"path/to/image.png":"a9ecbba8ef"`. Function `antiCache` should just change the URLs

```
function antiCache(fileHashes) {
    return through.obj(function (file, encoding, callback) {
    var content = file.contents.toString(),
        options = {};

    if (file.sourceMap) {
        options.outSourceMap = file.relative;
    }

    var mangled = (function() {
        var m = rework(file.contents.toString()).use(reworkUrl(function (url) {
            if (fileHashes.hasOwnProperty(path.basename(url))) {
                return url + '?' + fileHashes[path.basename(url)];
            }
            return url;
        }));
        m = css.stringify(m.obj, { sourcemap: true });
        m.code = new Buffer(m.code));
        return m;
    })();

    file.contents = mangled.code;
    if (file.sourceMap) {
        var map = mangled.map;
        map.file = path.relative(file.base, file.path);
        applySourceMap(file, map);
    }
    this.push(file);
    callback(null, file);
    });
}
```

Please help!